# Why is the water pressure low in my shower?

Tags: shower

I have low water pressure in shower.  I removed shower head but still very little water coming from pipe. Could it be the shower cartridge?  I have 1/2" pipe running from the water heater to the shower valve approximately 50'

Answer (score 2):

Shower cartridges can definitely get debris in them just like aerators in faucets can. Some valves have screen filters in them close to the intakes. also, make sure all your water valves are all the way open.

Comment: I regularly find rust and scale plugging them up even pieces of Teflon tape. +